# innovative integration co-processor

Tags: drivers, 18.04, hardware, repository

I am new in ubuntu and i want install co-processor product with innovative integration and nanotec dulcinea controll unit on ubuntu 18.04. any body can help me.
[co-processor info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bokwc.jpg)
[nanotec dulcinea controll unit info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FljM3.jpg)

Comment: You will need to get drivers/firmware from the manufacturer, to use such a device.

Comment: it's  manufacture  give an install from web exe file that not work . it say " for use with linux os, use a windows pc to download the files and transfer them to the target linux pc in a /usr/innonative folder. change permission on the "setup.sh" script yo make it executable. launch setup.sh to complete installation."

Comment: Then you need to contact them for support if it doesn't work. We can't provide support for proprietary products here.